# How to configure ASP.net Core to work with kubernetes NGINX ingress

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

i have a problem with ASP.Net Core and kubernetes ingress. I have 2 microservices a frontend and backend and With frontend i can see the website but all the wwwroot content is unavailable.

if i go to test.local/webui there is no CSS applied and dev tool outputs 404 for css file and when i hover over the css file it says it is looking at test.local/css/style.css instead of test.local/webui/css/style.css When i manualy go to test.local/webui/css/style.css css file is there.

ingressrule:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "test.local"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /webui
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webui
            port:
              number: 80
```

startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace rmn.WebUI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/webui");
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

i have also tried with different rewrite annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nsx"
    ncp/use-regex: "True"
    #/tea/cup will be rewritten to /cup before sending request to endpoint
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Is that rewrite target correct? Shouldn't it be /$1 ?